# SAS proq SQL: Conditionally summing and collapsing rows

Tags: sql, sas, sum, proc, proc-sql

In SAS, how to conditionally collapse rows, substituting with an explicitly name single row representing sum of values?

Specifically, I am looking to create a frequency table that displays the frequencies of value *Subclass*, but on the condition that that frequency is >9. In any other case (frequency <10), I want the frequency to count towards a sum of frequencies restricted to value *Class*. There are no missing or 0 values in the dataset.

```
Freq   Class  Subclass 
---------------------
20     1      1a        
20     1      1b       
 2     1      1c  
 2     1      1d
 2     1      1e
 1     1      1f
22     2      2a       
 6     2      2b        
 2     2      2c
 1     2      2d
31     3      3a        
17     3      3b        
 7     3      3c
 3     3      3d  
 3     3      3e
```

My current approach has produced the first table using:

```
proc sql;
   create table as
   select* count (distinct subjectID) as count
   from DATASET1 
   group by Subclass
   ; 
run; quit;
```

The desired result would look something like this:

```
Freq   Class  Subclass 
---------------------
20     1      1a        
20     1      1b       
 7     1      OTHER (1c, 1d, 1e, 1f) 
22     2      2a       
 9     2      OTHER (2b, 2c, 2d)        
31     3      3a        
17     3      3b        
13     3      OTHER (3c, 3d, 3e)
```

Preferably I would like to additionally explicitly name the *Subclass* value representing the the summed measurement according to identifiers of the measurements represented in the rows. In this example that would be the names of the subclasses summed up.

I have tried using the `Proc means` procedure, which yields a new dataset of all `Subclasses`with frequency <10, rather than a sum value.

Comment: freq 7 has class 3 in your have dataset. but it has class1 in want dataset. if possible can you show your intial sample dataset

Comment: In Class1, the frequencies for Subclass 1c, 1,d, 1e and 1f are 2, 2, 2 and 1 respectively. That makes a sum of 7 for all Subclasses within Class1 with a frequency of <10. Similarly, within Class3, Subclass 3c, 3d and 3e with respective frequencies 7, 3 and 3 make for a sum of 13 represented as "OTHER (3c, 3d, 3e)".

Answer (score 1):

A data step is the way to go to get your preferred output, utilizing the `first.` and `last.` statements.  This gives you options to output values >9 or sum the other values within same class.

The `call catx` function will concatenate the subclass values, so you can see which ones make up the frequency.

```
data have;
input Freq Class Subclass $;
datalines;
20     1      1a
20     1      1b
2     1      1c
2     1      1d
2     1      1e
1     1      1f
22     2      2a
6     2      2b
2     2      2c
1     2      2d
31     3      3a
17     3      3b
7     3      3c
3     3      3d
3     3      3e
;
run;

data want;
set have;
by class;
length subclass_groups $20 subclass_temp $20;
retain subclass_temp;
if first.class then call missing(freq_temp,subclass_temp);
if freq>9 then do;
    subclass_groups = subclass;
    output;
end;
else do;
    freq_temp + freq;
    call catx(',',subclass_temp,subclass);
end;
if last.class then do;
    freq = freq_temp;
    subclass_groups = subclass_temp;
    output;
end;
drop subclass subclass_temp freq_temp;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested code and this will make it easy to understand how to go about the issue by using union.

```
 proc sql;
create table as
select freq, class, subclass, count(subclass) as count
from DATASET1 
 where freq le 9
group by Subclass
union  all
select freq, class, subclass, count(class) as count
from DATASET1 
where freq ge 10
group by class;
```